# Run-time error '1004' when applying auto-filter on hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

On my UserForm, there is a button with this Click event:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Set rng = Range("A1:B100")
    End With

    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=1*"
    End With
End Sub
```

I want it to select the range **A1:B100** and apply auto-filter to this range on field 1 to select row start with number **1**.

If the sheet **Data** is visible, then the script works fine. However, if I choose to hide the sheet, then I got this run-time error 1004:

> The command could not be completed by using the range specified.
>   Select a single cell within the range and try the command again.

Can anybody help me with this please?

---

**Edit #1**: I tried this and the script worked:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    .Activate
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rng = Range("A1:B100")
End With
```

So maybe the sheet need to be *activated* before I can do anything on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:B100")
```

to:

```
Set rng = .Range("A1:B100")
```

The first way you are setting rng equal to `Range("A1:B100")` in the ActiveSheet, which wouldn't normally be a hidden sheet. Your trick of Activating the hidden sheet worked for the inverse reason, I think. Actually, I've never tried to activate a hidden sheet.

My sugggested way apecifies that `rng` is in "Data." It qualifies the range, just like you did with `AutofilterMode and the other properties inside your`With` statement.

At any rate, you generally want to avoid `Activates` in your code, for reasons that are discussed in a few other SO posts and elsewhere.

Comment: Just a little dot but you saved me a lot of headache. I also removed the `.Activate` method as you told me as well. Thank you very much for your help!